# Creating a zip and zip->close() returns false despite checks, path names are correct

Tags: php, zip

I've been trying to create a Zip file using PHP and the ZipArchive, but despite checking that each file I add is readable, writable, and exists, `zip->close()` returns false. If I call `zip->numFiles`, it returns the number I suspect, but `file_exists($zipname)` still returns false. Immediately after adding a file,   `$zip->getStatusString()` returns "No Error". If I call `$zip->getStatusString()` right after calling `zip->close()` it returns "Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied".

I've checked this link [Zip->close() returns false despite checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494674/zip-close-returns-false-despite-checks), and have ensured that the `$file` I'm making checks for is the exact same as the `$file` I'm adding to the `$zip`.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Do you have permission to create files in the directory you are trying to?  Or rather, does the web server?

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't even realise, I have redirected the zip to a writable directory. This solves this problem! Thanks

Comment: It's an amazingly common issue I've found coming up here quite a lot.  People wanting to create files and not having permission to write to the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, so this question does have an answer:

Whilst the files might be readable and writable, the location the zip archive is being written to also needs to be writable by the web server.

The number of files in the zip archive count are being counted because the zip stream is in memory at that stage, and not on disk.